# How to insert elements of two different python lists to two different rows in a MySQL table?

Tags: python, mysql

I have two python lists `list1` and `list2` and I am trying to insert the elements of `list1` into `col1` and elements of `list2` into `col2`.

I am using the following query:

```
query = """INSERT INTO table_name 
              (col1, col2) VALUES(%s,%s)"""
   cursor.executemany(query, [(l,) for l in list1], [(l,) for l in list2])
   connection.commit()
   print ("Record inserted successfully into ticket_details table")
```

And when I run my script, I get this following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "some.py", line 78, in <module>
    cursor.executemany(query, [(l,) for l in list1], [(l,) for l in list2])
TypeError: executemany() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am forming my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`executemany` is expecting 1 list of tuples, where each tuple has the values for a single insert; so something like this should do:

```
cursor.executemany(query,zip(list1,list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) seem to suggest this way:

```
query = """INSERT INTO table_name 
          (col1, col2) VALUES(%s,%s)"""
data = [
   [(l,) for l in list1],
   [(l,) for l in list2]
]
cursor.executemany(query, data)
```